How can I remove one Desktop folder from my iCloud Drive that keeps reappearing?
There is an empty folder entitled "Desktop" in my iCloud Drive. Whenever I delete it, it just reappears. I am not logged into iCloud on any Mac laptop or PC. My only devices are an iPhone, an iPad and an Apple Watch.
I tried turning iCloud Drive on & off, on every device I have. I tried looking in the settings. No matter what I do, that empty folder is still there and it cannot be deleted.
How can I get rid of it?

This is something you may need to open a support case with Apple to solve.
It is expected functionality to have a Desktop folder when a macOS device is signed in and enabled to sync.
Before you call, you might review each of the connected devices to be sure none are “lingering”

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102649

Keep notes on which you have access, and open a support case from the bottom of the link above (perhaps changing from the US English site based on which support group at Apple works in your country).
They can walk you through deleting the folder using a web session from the browser of your choice and confirm on the back end, why the delete is failing if needed.
